# Python - Average multiple matrices

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, mean

I am generating a set of M NxN-matrices such that M=10000 and N=1000. In other words, I am generating a large set of large matrices. My task is to average the M matrices element-wise.

The problem is that the code I wrote is not efficient, it takes quite a large time because I am iterating over all the matrix elements i,j:

```
rho_t=np.zeros((len(rho0),len(rho0),len(t_list)),dtype=np.complex64) 
for n_i,n in enumerate(t_list):
    for i in range(len(rho0)):
        for j in range(len(rho0)):
            rho_t[i,j,n_i]=np.mean(rho_tm[i,j,n_i,:])
```

here len(rho0)=1000, len(t_list)=500 and I am averaging over the last entry of np.mean(rho_tm[i,j,n_i,:])= 1/M sum^{m=0}^M rho_tm[i,j,n_i,m].

In there a way to avoid the summation over i,j? In other words, it is possible to use the np.mean simultaneously over all matrix elements without having to iterate over them?

Comment: You can use the `np.mean` function with the axis argument set to 0 to average the matrices element-wise.

Comment: @Phoenix oh you are completely right! I did work, thanks!